# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "XYZ_-1556021952300"

Tags: java

I have a string of chars and integers which I am splitting to take out the negative integer value and then check if the value is negative, then do something inside if block.
Code sample is as below:

```
java.util.Iterator<WebElement> i = elements.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    WebElement element = i.next();
    String str = element.getAttribute("name");
    System.out.println(str);
    String[] arrOfStr = str.split("_");
    System.out.println(arrOfStr);
    long res = Integer.parseInt(arrOfStr[1]);
    System.out.println(res);

    if (res < 0) {
        System.out.println("Inside if");
        System.out.println(data);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        Select selectBox = new Select(element);
        selectBox.selectByVisibleText(data);
    }
```

Comment: why are you parsing an integer using Integer.parseInt() into a long?

Comment: The number you are trying to parse is too big (small) to fit into an Integer. Try Long.parseLong

Comment: What about `arrOfStr[1].charAt(0) == '-'` as the condition for your `if` instead of `res < 0`?

Comment: try `long res = Long.parseLong(arrOfStr[1]);` instead of `Integer.parseInt(arrOfStr[1])`

Comment: Give an example of data which “arrOfStr[1]” will hold ...

Comment: Thanks All in Particular Jalynn,your solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse in Integer for input string: “XYZ_-1556021952300”. Since there is character which cannot be parse into number. So you are getting this exception.

May be because of the following code you are facing this issue.

```
long res = Integer.parseInt(arr0fStr[1]);
```

Change this line to something like this:

```
String res = arrOfStr[1];
```